# Internet is slow (tracert)

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection

So my internet is really slow. I just ran a tracert

```
Tracing route to www.google.com [204.186.55.247]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2   311 ms    30 ms    13 ms  XX.XX.0.1
  3    15 ms    12 ms    13 ms  gateway-t2-2-1580-my-internet.net [XXX.XX.XX.XX]
  4    14 ms    15 ms    18 ms  204.186.55.247
```

Looking at line 2. Is that telling me that my slow down is where I am going from my router to my ISP? Is this an ISP issue or my issue?

[image]

Comment: If your router's outbound port is an ethernet connection (as opposed to a cable-tv coaxial connection, for example), then you can test by disconnecting your router and connecting your computer directly. This would be a worthwhile test.

Comment: What bufferbloat score do you get from http://dslreports.com/speedtest ?

Comment: @Spiff updated post with image

Answer (score 0):

You apparently have good latency values, the higher latency you see just at your 2nd hop is probably related to the way that specific router of your ISP replies to ICMP echo requests... for example the router may be setup to delay (or even drop it) them if there are too many simultaneous requests (including from other users).

You have rather good latency values for the next hops and apparently stable, then there is probably nothing wrong with latency on your connection. However you may confirm that with a longer test like using WinMTR software.

Concerning download/upload throughput speed, we can't reply you if it is normal, it will just depend of the Internet service you contracted... it would be normal for some ADSL connections... please give us more details...

Also if you are connecting by WiFi you should test again connecting by Ethernet cable instead, however I guess that is not the case or you would probably get higher upload speed (more similar to download one).